# C# Timetabling/Scheduling

Tags: c#, schedule

So I'm creating a timetabling software that arranges work in the most optimal arrangement. There are 2 types of activities, work (has priority and duration) and fixed work (has start and end time)

The final arrangement must fulfill the following conditions:

- The max amount of time of consecutive work is 1.5 hours
- The minimum break time between these "blocks" of work is 15 mins
- Soft constraint is to place work in order of priority

So I've split up the arrangement into 5 minutes intervals and placed in the fixed events (since start and end time is known). But I'm not too sure what is the optimum way to arrange the work is.

[image: sleepy time is the fixed event from 15.15 to 15.55]

How would I be able to fulfill all the conditions mentioned above while making an arrangement? All help is much appreciated. If there's any technical name for such a problem as this, please let me know so I can go search

If there are any issues with how I asked the question or formatting, please let me know so I fix it in future

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show us the code you've written so far. Also, please don't ask us to write code for you. Have a go at writing this yourself and we'll help you when you get stuck. If you get stuck before you can write any code relating to the scheduling then please ask us a specific question about what you're actually stuck at.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did I didn't phrase it clearly, I'm not trying to get people to write code for me. I'm just curious about how it can be implemented, like how would one go about solving such a problem.

Comment: We're not a design team either. Please present your design and as much code as you can. We can help you get unstuck. The key here is providing as much of your code as possible.